# Get anchor InnerText in a nested Divs

Tags: html-agility-pack

Html :

```
 <div class="info">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="{DYNAMIC CLASS NAME}">
                <a href="link">Text</a>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="{DYNAMIC CLASS NAME}">
                <a href="link">Another Text</a>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

XPath :

```
    DocumentNode.SelectNodes["//div[@class='info']/div[2]/a"];
```

How to get a innertext value from nested divs? 
Because 3rd div classname is a dynamic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using index, like `div[2]`, to get nested `<div>` is not correct. You should've used `div/div` instead. Try this way :

```
DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='info']/div[@class='title']/div/a");
```